# Kruskall-Wallis test. How many degrees of freedom to report?

Tags: r, anova, nonparametric, kruskal-wallis-test

I have run a kruskall-wallis test to see if there is a significant difference in the amount of fish at each site.

There are three sites (Site1, Site2 and Site3), with 80 observations of fish in each column/site, resulting in a 3 x 80 table. For example....

```
Site1 Site2 Site3
40  0   90
50  5   90
35  20  90
40  25  50
60  5   50
10  8   95
50  5   5
```

I'm however unsure on the degrees of freedom to report.

Would it be Fish (H=17.18, DF=2, p<0.05), where DF is related to the number of sites.

Or would it be (H=17.18, DF=237, p<0.05), where DF is related to the total number of samples/observations taken (80 * 3) - 3)).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The former, n=2, between-groups df, because the number of sites (treatment levels) minus one is the number of independent states this system can take. In other words, re-shuffling the data within a column does not change the outcome of analysis (there is *no freedom*), it is not a pivot point on which the system's state can change.